# Find the index of multi-rows

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, row

> Suppose I have a dataframe called df as follows:
>   
>        `A_column  B_column   C_column
>   0      Apple       100        15
>   1      Banana      80         20
>   2      Orange      110        10
>   3      Apple       150        16
>   4      Apple       90         13`

[Q] How to list the index [0,3,4] for Apple in A_column?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean 'list' an index. Do you mean just extract rows 0, 3 and 4 from the table? or something else? What output would you expect for that?

Comment: I want to get the values 0, 3, and 4 from table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the row indexes as list to `df.iloc`

```
>>> df
  A_column  B_column  C_column
0    Apple       100        15
1   Banana        80        20
2   Orange       110        10
3    Apple       150        16
4    Apple        90        13

>>> df.iloc[[0,3,4]]
  A_column  B_column  C_column
0    Apple       100        15
3    Apple       150        16
4    Apple        90        13
```

EDIT: seems i misunderstood your questions

So you want to have the list containing the index number of the rows containing 'Apple', you can use `df.index[df['A_column']=='Apple'].tolist()`

```
>>> df.index[df['A_column']=='Apple'].tolist()
[0, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I get the wanted answer.